# Tensorflow: How to convert a data in 2D shape into 3D shape (Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes, lstm, sequential

I'm new to tensorflow and python.

Currently obtained data of shape **[5639, 13]**
Want to split the 5639 into 20sets and obtain a 3D shape of **[___, 20, 13]**
as i want it to be **sequential matrix**.
How can I do it?

Comment: try the reshape function

Comment: Thanks, I successfully reshaped the **[5639, 13]** into **[1, 5639, 13]**. But how do i split the 5639 into sequential of 20 seq_length, which is the shape of  **[5639//seq_len, seq_len, 13]** ? :) @Paddy

Comment: have you seen this page https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape ?

Comment: viewed. why when i am reshaping **[1, 5639, 13]** into **[352, 16, 13]**, there is error? Since its already in 3D........

My code: 
X3D = np.reshape(X2D, [1, 5639, len_feat])
--> **output : [1, 5639, 13]**

X3D = np.reshape(X3D, [5639//seq_len, seq_len, len_feat])
 --> **expected: [352, 16, 13]**

@Paddy

Comment: but 352 * 16 != 5639, maybe you should remove 7 lines.

Comment: Cus 5639//16 they take int, which is 352. What's an alternative that i can do to obtain what i want? @Paddy